# Changing arrays inside a function in C w/o a pointer using memory addresses

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, pointers

While learning about pointers, arrays and functions on tutorials point I realised that I could achieve my goal of returning an array from a function by creating a new array in the main function, creating a pointer and assigning the return value of the function to this pointer and then using a for loop in the  **main**  function incrementing the pointer to reassign the values of the array to the array internal to the sorting function.

However I was wondering since the memory is returned to the stack after the function returns how come the values in the array aren't reassigned to something else and secondly is there a way I could using memory addresses change the actual array in the main function inside the sorting functions and then return void? I am using a bubble sort algorithm, this is my current sorting function;

```
#include <stdbool.h>
int *arr_sort(int *arr){    

int *ptr = arr;
bool flag = true;
while(flag){

    flag = false;
    int i = 0;
    for(i;i<4;i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
            flag = true;
            arr[i]+=arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = arr[i]-arr[i+1];
            arr[i]-= arr[i+1];
            }

        //  printf("%d : %d\t%d : %d \n",i,arr[i],i+1,arr[i+1]); *Included to display the values as they are being switched
    }
printf("\n\n");
}   

return arr;
```

}

Then the for loop in the main that assigned my array (called unsorted_array) to the pointer as it is incremented through the array created inside the sorting function

```
    ptr = arr_sort(unsorted_array);
        for(j;j<5;j++){
        unsorted_array[j]=*(ptr+j);
```

The whole thing works as a program but I was just wondering in the interest of building up knowledge (Haven't been programming in C for long), is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by w/o?

Comment: Yeh sorry, didn't want to make the title too long

Comment: `for(i;i<4;i++){` is bogus. did you mean: `for(i=0; ...` ?

Comment: nope. int i is initialised outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

No need to return array from your function. Just define your function as

```
void arr_sort(int *arr){    

     bool flag = true;
     while(flag){

         flag = false;
         int i;
         for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
              if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
                   flag = true;
                   arr[i]+=arr[i+1];
                   arr[i+1] = arr[i]-arr[i+1];
                   arr[i]-= arr[i+1];
              }

         }
         printf("\n\n");
     }   
}
```

Any and all changes to `arr` will be made to the array in `main`.

Comment: I tried that and couldn't get it to work. I'll try again though. will the function return type be void

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you, with "creating a new array in the main function" mean something like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
   char unsorted_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
   // ... Code
}
```

Any variable, (trivial, pointer or array) located on the stack is kept while *calling* another function, but any variable located on the stack by the *called* function is invalidated when the function returns.

But: a pointer located on the stack may point to an array on the heap. That is if the array is either allocated by malloc(), being declared as static inside the function, or being a global variable. In that case, the content of the array is of course kept as the function returns, and can be made available to the *calling* function by e.g returning the pointer. Only the pointer (e.g. typically 4 bytes) is copied to the *calling* function stack as the function returns, not the array which the pointer points to.

Similarly, an array located on the stack may be made available to a *called* function, by supplying the *called* function with a pointer to the array, just as you do. What is copied to the *called* function's stack, is only the pointer (4 bytes), hence the called function may access and modify the array, and the array itself is *not* invalidated as the function returns.

NB: in C, when invoking a function declared as

```
void afun(char anarray[ARRAY_SIZE);
```

the compiler implicitly treats the function as if it was declared as

```
void afun(char *anarray);
```

i.e. calling `afun` only copies the pointer, not the array to the called function's stack.